Is it possible to edit / update Keycloak's Infinispan cache?
Keycloak offers several REST calls to retrieve client or user sessions from it's builtin Infinispan cache. It is also possible to delete sessions via the REST API.
I'd like to know if it is possible to update sessions programmatically in a custom SPI. The Javadoc lists some Infinispan-related methods but it's not clear to me if these can be used for that purpose.
Does anyone know if this can be done, either with the default builtin Infinispan cache, or with an external Infinispan server?
For the time being we are stuck with Keycloak v23.0.7 because we first need to re-build our custom theme to work with v24+.
Thanks!

First, make sure there really aren't public admin REST API calls exposed for your use case, by reviewing the reference at https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/latest/rest-api/index.html
While I am not familiar with what public APIs/SPIs Keycloak actually provides, looking at the linked Javadoc, these do not appear public API/SPI. Which means that things can change without warning in the next version. Nevertheless, you should be able to implement a Keycloak extension to achieve what you need, see linked extensions for reference/inspiration: https://www.keycloak.org/extensions

Thank you. The existing REST API calls allow reading session information and deleting them, but no editing / updating. Luckily I was able to convince my colleagues to prioritise updating the theme which allows us to move to V25+ which allows storing user and client sessions in the database instead of only in Infinispan.

That definitely sounds like the best solution. If you were to externalize the sessions to another Infinispan cluster, you are getting yourself into a new set of challenges such as dealing with consistency, concurrent access, serialization compatibility, etc.
